# Cannot start meteor and mongo on windows 10?

Tags: windows, mongodb, meteor

I get an error

> C:\Users\pavle\AppData\Local.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.3.4_1\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\server-lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:280
>
> Error: URL must be in the format mongodb: // user: pass @ host: port / dvname

I do not understand, because of what is happening. I tried to install as
I tried so:

```
set MONGO_URL="mongodb://127.0.0.1:7777/mongo" && meteor --port 8031 --settings local-settings.json
set MONGO_URL="mongodb://root:password@127.0.0.1:7777/mongo" && meteor --port 8031 --settings local-settings.json
```

Set in settings file

```
  "env":{
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://root:password@localhost:7777/zenmarket"
  }
  "env":{
    "MONGO_URL": "mongodb://@localhost:7777/zenmarket"
  }
```

mongod port 7777

Windows 10 64

Meteor v1.3.4.1

Mongo shell v3.2.7

I'm desperate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent a few hours on it to understand the reason.
As always, it is simple
It is necessary to set the URL without the quotes

> set MONGO_URL=mongodb://root:password@127.0.0.1:7777/mongo

Check that you should simply

> echo% MONGO_URL%

Hopefully this will help someone